# Subprocess Run SSH Python3

Tags: python, ssh

I would like to connect to a network device like a Cisco router through Python with a SSH connection, I am using Subprocess but when it is a new device or the RSA key has been replaced and the message does not appear that if I want to replace the RSA key and the program terminates.

Question about replacing the RSA key:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.10.129 (192.168.10.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? no
Host key verification failed.
```

Line of code I have:

```
subprocess.run(['ssh',v_user+'@'+v_ip])
```

What do I have to do to get this message to appear and enter yes?

Comment: Option 1: connect manually from terminal once, [Option 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh)

Comment: Why do you think you want this? If you just want to collect host keys there are better ways to do it.